# Positions from GPS lanes inside polygon using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, point-in-polygon

I have a lot of lanes like the orange lanes in the below picture (latitude and longitude values).

[image: example]
Now I need all values from each lane inside the red polygon. What is the easiest way to realize this using PostGIS? I am not a GIS expert ;)

I would like read/load the files with lat/lon values, define the corners of the polygon (lat/lon??) and the output are all positions from each lane inside the polygon.

Comment: When you say all values, at what frequency, or are those lines in fact multiple points, rather than  single lines. There is a function, [ST_Line_Interpolate_Point](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html) that might help, which you can use in conjunction with ST_Intersection.

Comment: the values are not interpolated. for the lanes i have every second values from a gps logger.

Comment: What are you trying to produce, a track? Or simply all the points that are in inside the red polygon?

Comment: I need all points from each lane separately to produce all tracks (for this example 4) inside.

Answer (score 2):

In **Postgis** you can accomplish this by using the [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) function. There is even an example there of this exact problem, building a line from GPS tracks. In your case, you will want to also include the [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) function, so that you only use those points that are inside you red box (aoi).

```
SELECT gps.gps_track, ST_MakeLine(gps.geom ORDER BY gps_time) As newgeom
FROM gps_points As gps, aoi
WHERE ST_Intersects(gps.geom, aoi.geom)
GROUP BY gps.gps_track;
```

This assumes you have Postgres 9.0 and up and that your red box is a geometry called geom in a table called aoi. In practice, you might just want to use `ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((x1 y1, x2 y2....xn, yn, x1, y1))')` instead of having a separate table for aoi, in which case the query would look like:

```
SELECT gps.gps_track, ST_MakeLine(gps.geom ORDER BY gps_time) As newgeom
FROM gps_points As gps
WHERE ST_Intersects(gps.geom, ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON(....))'))
GROUP BY gps.gps_track;
```

You will also want to put a spatial index on you gps tracks table for any non-trivial size.

Note, I have changed the name of the geometry column in the official docs from the_geom to geom (personal preference).

Comment: Does that do what you want?